# Custom command to generate object(.o) from binary file using autoconf

Tags: c++, linux, autoconf, automake, objcopy

We have a project (c++) and it needs to include a binary file into shared library. This is done on windows by referencing the binary file from a resource file. On Linux it can be achieved by using objcopy as shown [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967)

The question is how can this be automated this using autoconf/automake? There exists Makefile.am and configure.ac files. Is this going to be a manual task?

*(Maybe this question needs to be on the [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site?)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your binary file have a distinctive extension? If so, refer to the [Suffixes](http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Suffixes) chapter of the manual:

```
.bin.o:
        bin2o -o $@ $<
```

And you then list `foo.bin` in your `foo_SOURCES` variable.

If you don't have a distinctive extension, try something like this:

```
foo_SOURCES = foo.c bar.c baz.c
foo_LDADD = foobin$(OBJEXT)

foobin$(OBJEXT): foobin
        bin2o -o $@ $<
```

Comment: That worked a treat. Thanks.
Sorry can;t upvote the answer as I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: In the second case, you may want to add `foobin$(OBJEXT)` to `CLEANFILES`, so it's removed by `make clean`.